# Field kafkaTemplate in ... required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Before marking this as a duplicate, please recognize that I have looked at other stack overflow links with similar errors, but their solutions don't actually work in this instance.

**What I am trying to do :**
I want to send a regular old java obect to a kafka queue so that I may use it as an event in another service.

**What seems to be broken :**
I am following examples from all over the internet, and all of them result in the bean not being found. Perhaps examples are outdated and I missed something?

**I have the following config class :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, NotificationEvent> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, NotificationEvent> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

**I also have this kafka sender class :**

```
@Service
public class KafkaSender {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String,NotificationEvent> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String kafkaTopic, NotificationEvent notification) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, notification);
    }
}
```

**Notification class:**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class NotificationEvent {
    private String bucket;
    private String prefix;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [bucket=" + bucket + ", prefix="
                + prefix + "]";
    }
}
```

**Actual Error output :**

```
Field kafkaTemplate in <Removed to keep things generic> required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Comment: We can't guess what's wrong from just selected code snippets; post a minimal reproducible complete project someplace so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell without the full code but it looks like you're using lombok and it's interfering with your spring configuration. If you remove the all args annotation and replace with proper constructor injection, I think you'll find it works.